# Return a variable's value from a method of the constructor to another method using a thread daemon

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have this part of a script in `python`:

```
class Filtro:
    def __init__(self,cmd):
       def exec_cmd():
            proc = subprocess.Popen([cmd, '-'],
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        )
            return proc

       self.thr=threading.Thread(name="Demone_cmd",target=exec_cmd)
       self.thr.setDaemon(True)
       self.proc=self.thr.start()

    def inp(self,txt):
       f=open(txt,"r")
       self.proc.communicate(f.read())
       f.close()


filtro=Filtro(sys.argv[1])
filtro.inp(sys.argv[2])
```

I want the return value of `exec_cmd` -- i.e., `proc` -- in the method `inp`, but the current code doesn't achieve this -- communication between the methods doesn't work.

Comment: Please fix your indentation in the post.

Comment: ok, I have identation my code

Comment: why wouldn't you just make `exec_cmd` a method of `Filtro`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct cause of your problem is in `self.proc = self.thr.start()`: the `start()` method starts a thread and has no return value. So `self.proc` is set to `None` there and `self.proc.communicate(f.read())` will cause an exception.

More generally the use of threads in your snippet seems a bit overkill, `subprocess.Popen()` in itself already starts a process that runs in parallel with your script, and you can use its `communicate()` method to send data to the process and retrieve the process results ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)).

An important detail using `communicate()` is to start the process with a pipe for stdout and stderr, else you will not get the process results back. So if you replace your constructor with the following, you should be able to see process results in your `inp()` method:

```
def __init__(self,cmd):
    self.proc = subprocess.Popen([cmd, '-'], 
                                stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```